# How to display posts by category without foreach?

Tags: php, loops, dynamic, laravel-8

Good evening everyone, I am a real beginner in php. I'm trying to display my posts by category in a clickable menu, I succeeded by doing this foreach loop. They are sorted by category but unfortunately, they are all displayed whereas I would like only the posts of a chosen category to be displayed. I'm a bit lost with the loops... Can you help me to correct this code? Thanks in advance...

```
  @foreach($categories as $category)
    <h1>Les {{ count($category->posts) }} articles de la catégorie <br/>"{{ $category->name}}"
        </h1>
       
        <!-- Liste des posts de la catégorie -->
        @include('posts.index', ['posts' => $category->posts])
    
    @endforeach
```

I have attached a picture of the result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" will be in the class where you are rendering this view. It should be searching all categories.

```php
\App\Models\Category::all()
```

Instead, you should only select the category you want.

```php
\App\Models\Category::firstWhere('name', 'name_of_category')
```

*The above code is just an example, you should filter according to the criteria you need.*

And in your code, you can put the code that is inside the loop out.

```php
{{-- @foreach($categories as $category) Remove this line --}}
    <h1>Les {{ count($category->posts) }} articles de la catégorie <br/>"{{ $category->name}}"
        </h1>
       
        <!-- Liste des posts de la catégorie -->
        @include('posts.index', ['posts' => $category->posts])
    
   {{-- @endforeach Remove this line --}}
```